# DOM not updating on $http POST request with MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have a app that performs CRUD operations on a Mongo database. I have a form input and want to list the elements below the form in real time as they are added. As of now, the elements only appear on page refresh. However, I have an "x" that calls an `ng-click` to delete the item (and subsequently delete the item from the database) and these items will disappear immediately from the DOM (without page refresh). I'm performing the POST and DELETE requests in the same manner, using promises for both. I can't figure out why the delete requests automatically update the DOM, but the post requests do not.

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('ListController', function($scope, PlaceService) {

    $scope.places = [];

    getPlaces();
    function getPlaces() {
        PlaceService.findAll().then(function(promise) {
            // $scope.places updates correctly, but DOM doesn't show it
            $scope.places = promise.data
        });
    };

    $scope.submit = function(place) {
        if (!place) return alert('No content submitted');
        PlaceService.submit(place).then(function(data) {
            getPlaces();
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    };

    $scope.remove = function(id) {
        PlaceService.remove(id).then(function(data) {
            getPlaces();
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

});
```

`PlaceService` is a factory that communicates with the API, and is as follows:

```
app.factory('PlaceService', function($http, $q) {

    return {

        findAll: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/places').then(function(response) {
                console.log('Get Request Successful');
                return deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        remove: function(id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.delete('/places/' + id).then(function(response) {
                console.log('Delete Successful');
                return deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        submit: function(entry) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var jObj = JSON.stringify(entry);
            $http.post('/places', jObj).then(function(response) {
                console.log('Post Successful');
                return deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }
});
```

I'm trying to get `$scope.places` to reflect updates in the DOM, I've tried wrapping the `$scope.places` expression in `$timeout` but to no avail.

**TLDR: `$scope.places` not reflecting changes made in controller**

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `.then()` in your `$scope.submit` and `$scope.remove` functions to ensure that your `getPlaces()` function is only run once the POST or DELETE is complete.

Comment: See @mcranston18's answer for the syntax, which I was just about to add to my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`PlaceService.submit(place)` is a `$q` promise. This means, if you want to call `getPlaces();` once a "place" has been successfully submitted, you should place it in your callback:

```
PlaceService.submit(place)
   .then(function(data) {
      getPlaces();
   }, function(error) {
    // handle your error
   });
```

You will also want to handle your `PlaceService.remove(place)` method the same way.

Comment: I added the `then` callback to submit (and delete) as you suggested but the DOM still isn't updating. I also did `console.log(data)` and the Post request is successful, but for some reason `getPlaces()` isn't storing the updated data to `$scope.places`... See edits.